# Javascript: how to open a popup with dimensions from the image file?

Tags: javascript, image, popup

I am migrating a large volume of HTML content to a new platform. The source files contain width and height information in the  tags, but these dimensions are wrong.

I would like to open the images in a popup window, but with the correct dimensions of the source file. I have already replaced all the original  tags with an anchor that links to a popup script.

The problem I am having is that if I use the width and height provided in the HTML document, the popup is too small; but as soon as I add javascript to read the real dimensions before opening the popup (using the naturalHeight and naturalWidth attributes), the image opens in a new tab and the popup no longer launches.

Here's the popup code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function wopen(url, name, w, h) { //w and h are incorrect but available in the HTML
    w += 32; //padding for scrollbars and borders
    h += 96;
    var win = window.open(url,
    name, 
    'width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', ' +
    'location=no, menubar=no, ' +
    'status=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes');
    win.resizeTo(w, h);
    win.focus();
    }
</script>
```

I have tried using simple functions to get the real dimensions. For example, if I call the function getimagewidth below in the popup script, the image loads in a new tab and the window.open method doesn't create a popup.

```
function getimagewidth(i)
{
var x=new Image;
x.src=i;
return x.naturalWidth;
}
```

I have also tried modifying the popup script to read the attributes naturalWidth and naturalHeight, then pass these attributes to window.open or window.resizeTo. The same thing happens, in that any line of code that references the image also opens it in a new tab and the popup doesn't launch. For example, I have tried adding these lines:

```
var x=document.getElementByID(url);
rw=x.naturalWidth;
rh=x.naturalHeight;
```

Followed by

```
var win = window.open( same parameters as above, replacing w and h with rw and rh )
```

Or

```
win.resizeTo(rw, rh);
```

Just to add icing on the cake, the pages must work correctly in a chromium-based proprietary browser; this means that win.resizeTo will not necessarily work.

I don't really know what's going wrong with this, but I hope I have clearly explained what I want to accomplish. Is there any way for my wopen function to open initially with the correct size, not knowing the size beforehand?

Comment: This bit ````function getimagewidth(i)
{
var x=new Image;
x.src=i;
return x.naturalWidth;
}```` doesn't open a new tab, by default, in chrome.  Not sure why you are seeing that.

Comment: However if that does happen, what I would suggest is: have a hidden image on your html page; load the image in there, then get width; and then open it in a popup.